# cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, qt

I'm trying to build the *qt-gstreamer-1.2.0* package listed [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/qt-gstreamer/). But when I run `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/installation/` according to the README file I encounter the `cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` error.
When I check whether it is actually available or not via `find /usr -name "libidn.so.11" -print` I can't seem to find it.
I've tried installing the *libidn11:i386* but I came across the `E: Unable to locate package libidn11:i386` error, so I installed the *libidn11-dev:i386* but it didn't solve this issue either.
I also came across this issue on different scenarios not just this one in particular. If it helps I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will help, but according to [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libidn) the package libidn11 is not included into 22.04LTS version, instead there is a libidn12. So, I am afraid, that you can not compile *qt-gstreamer-1.2.0* package in your distribution without additional hacks.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate that a package this common is only available in 20.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue, why not try this way below:

```
ln -s  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.12.x /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11
```